# Python unit test naming convention for module functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, naming-conventions

When writing tests I usually name the modules prefixed with `test_` for example `spam.py` and `test_spam.py`. This makes finding the tests easy. When testing classes in a module I create a `unittest.TestCase` derivative with a similar class name, postfixed with `Test`. e.g. `Spam` becomes `SpamTest` (not `TestSpam` as this sounds like it is a test implementation of `Spam`). Then class functions are tested by test functions that are prefixed with `test_` and postfixed with `_testcondition` or some other descriptive postfix. I find that this works brilliantly as the original object names are included.

The problem occurs when I want to test module level functions. Following my regular structure I would create a `unittest.TestCase` derivative with the same name as the function, postfixed with `Test`. The problem with this is that class names are camel cased and function names are lower cased with underscores to separate words. Ignoring the naming convention `some_function` becomes `SomeFunctionTest`. I cannot help but feeling that this is ugly.

What would be a better fit? What is common practice? Is there a 'standard' like pep8 for this? What do you use?

Comment: Honestly? I can't say it matters. Just be consistent.

Answer (score 6):

The way you are doing it is the cleanest approach - as long as there is a clear location where people would expect to find the tests for a module level function then I think you are good. The stylistic difference between the function name and the test class name - although an annoyance - isn't significant enough to worry about.